# Send Thumbwheel data to serial just once

Tags: c, avr

im working with thumbwheel on my prject. i need to send the data to serial just once so the reciever can do something with it. however, the code i made keep sending the data continuously to the serial, can someone enlighten me please? and, im using AVR btw.

here is my code`

```
uint8_t fii = 0;
uint8_t previousfii = 0;


int main(void)
{
    setUp32MhzInternalOsc();
    setUpSerial();

    stdout = &usart_output;
    stdin = &usart_input;


   //thumbwheel 2B
   PORTF.DIRCLR     =    PIN1_bm;
   PORTF.PIN1CTRL   =    PORT_OPC_PULLUP_gc;

   PORTF.DIRCLR     =    PIN2_bm;
   PORTF.PIN2CTRL   =    PORT_OPC_PULLUP_gc;

   PORTF.DIRCLR     =    PIN3_bm;
   PORTF.PIN3CTRL   =    PORT_OPC_PULLUP_gc;


while(1)
{


    //thumbwheel 2B 
    if (!(PORTF.IN&PIN3_bm))
    {
        if (fii != 1)
        {
            fii = fii+1;
        }
    }

    if (!(PORTF.IN&PIN1_bm))
    {
        if (fii != 2)
        {
            fii = fii+2;
        }
    }

    if (!(PORTF.IN&PIN2_bm))
    {
        if (fii != 4)
        {
            fii = fii+4;
        }
    }


    printf("%d\n", fii);
    fii = 0;
    //_delay_ms(500);

}


            }
```

Comment: "just once" is probably also not what you want. Maybe you want to send data when one of the pins changes?

Comment: yes.. thats what i man sir

Comment: See my answer. But its a pretty obvious way to to it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be sufficient if you send `fii` every time when it changes. So use something like this:

```
int main(void) {
    uint8_t fii = 0;
    uint8_t previousFii = 0;

    // < other init code here >

    while(1) {
        // < your other code here >

        if (fii != previousFii) {
            previousFii = fii;
            printf("%d\n", fii);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing related to my answer. You haven't shown your full code, so I assumed you have PORT direction initializations or some other stuff somewhere.

Comment: You should be able to understand and use my solution. I am not doing everything for you here ;)

Comment: i know man, but i dont know what to add in <another init code> there, i mean i dont get the logic. it supposed to end where you write there